# 19.10: Plasma Discover takes a long time before enabling the "update all" button

Tags: kubuntu, 19.10, discover-software-center

I've ran into a strange issue today. After clicking on the "you have updates" icon on the notification panel, discover refreshed sources, found updates for the kernel and... nothing. The `update all` button didn't appear for at least 20s, so I closed discover, clicked on the notification and got greeted with the same result. So finally I started discover from the terminal to see if it was throwing any errors.

There were plenty! The text up to the TypeError's showed up quite quickly, and the rest of the messages, as well as the missing `update all`, appeared while I was searching for the error message in ubuntu's bugzilla. No luck on that front though. I did find a [image: reddit post with a similar error] suggesting I need to reinstall discover. I ran `sudo apt install --reinstall plasma-discover`, but discover didn't get back to it's usual speed afterwards.

```bsh
user@laptop:~$ plasma-discover
adding empty sources model QStandardItemModel(0x563937bbc640)
no packages for "org.kde.plasma.quicklaunch"
no packages for "org.kde.plasma.systemloadviewer"
no packages for "android-sdk"
no packages for "org.kde.plasma.showActivityManager"
no packages for "libgphoto2"
no packages for "org.kde.plasma.grouping"
no packages for "org.kde.plasma.diskquota"
no packages for "org.kde.plasma.timer"
no packages for "org.kde.kscreen"
no packages for "libu2f-udev"
no packages for "org.kde.plasma.appmenu"
no packages for "im.riot.webapp"
no packages for "org.kde.plasma.kimpanel"
no packages for "org.cockpit_project.cockpit"
invalid kns backend! "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/ksysguard.knsrc" because: "Config group not found! Check your KNS3 installation."
took really long to fetch KNSBackend(0x563939dddc40, name = "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/window-decorations.knsrc")
took really long to fetch KNSBackend(0x56393a03b2d0, name = "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/cgctheme.knsrc")
took really long to fetch KNSBackend(0x563939de83a0, name = "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/icons.knsrc")
took really long to fetch KNSBackend(0x563939de81e0, name = "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/cgcgtk3.knsrc")
took really long to fetch KNSBackend(0x563939682350, name = "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/aurorae.knsrc")
took really long to fetch KNSBackend(0x5639396975d0, name = "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/emoticons.knsrc")
took really long to fetch KNSBackend(0x56393969aaf0, name = "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/kwinswitcher.knsrc")
took really long to fetch KNSBackend(0x56393967f8d0, name = "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/discover_ktexteditor_codesnippets_core.knsrc")
took really long to fetch KNSBackend(0x563939690a80, name = "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/kwineffect.knsrc")
took really long to fetch KNSBackend(0x5639396943a0, name = "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/kwinscripts.knsrc")
took really long to fetch KNSBackend(0x563939694940, name = "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/sddmtheme.knsrc")
took really long to fetch KNSBackend(0x56393967fb20, name = "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/wallpaperplugin.knsrc")
took really long to fetch KNSBackend(0x56393969b900, name = "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/wallpaper.knsrc")
took really long to fetch KNSBackend(0x5639396a42a0, name = "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/lookandfeel.knsrc")
took really long to fetch KNSBackend(0x5639396b11f0, name = "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/plasma-themes.knsrc")
took really long to fetch KNSBackend(0x5639396a9140, name = "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/xcursor.knsrc")
took really long to fetch KNSBackend(0x563939695b80, name = "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/comic.knsrc")
took really long to fetch KNSBackend(0x56393969ccc0, name = "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/plasmoids.knsrc")
took really long to fetch KNSBackend(0x5639396a7490, name = "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/colorschemes.knsrc")
took really long to fetch KNSBackend(0x56393969f630, name = "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/ksplash.knsrc")
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/ScrollablePage.qml:187: TypeError: Cannot assign to read-only property "parent"
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/ScrollablePage.qml:187: TypeError: Cannot assign to read-only property "parent"
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/ScrollablePage.qml:187: TypeError: Cannot assign to read-only property "parent"
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/ScrollablePage.qml:187: TypeError: Cannot assign to read-only property "parent"
invalid kns backend! "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/window-decorations.knsrc" because: "Backend Window Decorations took too long to initialise"
org.kde.plasma.libdiscover: Discarding invalid backend "window-decorations.knsrc"
invalid kns backend! "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/icons.knsrc" because: "Backend Icons took too long to initialise"
org.kde.plasma.libdiscover: Discarding invalid backend "icons.knsrc"
invalid kns backend! "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/aurorae.knsrc" because: "Backend Aurorae Window Decorations took too long to initialise"
org.kde.plasma.libdiscover: Discarding invalid backend "aurorae.knsrc"
invalid kns backend! "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/emoticons.knsrc" because: "Backend Emoticons took too long to initialise"
org.kde.plasma.libdiscover: Discarding invalid backend "emoticons.knsrc"
invalid kns backend! "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/kwinswitcher.knsrc" because: "Backend Window Manager Switching Layouts took too long to initialise"
org.kde.plasma.libdiscover: Discarding invalid backend "kwinswitcher.knsrc"
invalid kns backend! "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/discover_ktexteditor_codesnippets_core.knsrc" because: "Backend Kate Snippets took too long to initialise"
org.kde.plasma.libdiscover: Discarding invalid backend "discover_ktexteditor_codesnippets_core.knsrc"
invalid kns backend! "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/kwineffect.knsrc" because: "Backend Window Manager Effects took too long to initialise"
org.kde.plasma.libdiscover: Discarding invalid backend "kwineffect.knsrc"
invalid kns backend! "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/kwinscripts.knsrc" because: "Backend Window Manager Scripts took too long to initialise"
org.kde.plasma.libdiscover: Discarding invalid backend "kwinscripts.knsrc"
invalid kns backend! "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/sddmtheme.knsrc" because: "Backend Login Screen took too long to initialise"
org.kde.plasma.libdiscover: Discarding invalid backend "sddmtheme.knsrc"
invalid kns backend! "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/wallpaperplugin.knsrc" because: "Backend Wallpaper Plugins took too long to initialise"
org.kde.plasma.libdiscover: Discarding invalid backend "wallpaperplugin.knsrc"
invalid kns backend! "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/wallpaper.knsrc" because: "Backend Wallpapers took too long to initialise"
org.kde.plasma.libdiscover: Discarding invalid backend "wallpaper.knsrc"
invalid kns backend! "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/lookandfeel.knsrc" because: "Backend Look and Feel took too long to initialise"
org.kde.plasma.libdiscover: Discarding invalid backend "lookandfeel.knsrc"
invalid kns backend! "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/plasma-themes.knsrc" because: "Backend Plasma Themes took too long to initialise"
org.kde.plasma.libdiscover: Discarding invalid backend "plasma-themes.knsrc"
invalid kns backend! "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/xcursor.knsrc" because: "Backend Cursors took too long to initialise"
org.kde.plasma.libdiscover: Discarding invalid backend "xcursor.knsrc"
invalid kns backend! "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/comic.knsrc" because: "Backend Comics took too long to initialise"
org.kde.plasma.libdiscover: Discarding invalid backend "comic.knsrc"
invalid kns backend! "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/plasmoids.knsrc" because: "Backend Plasma Widgets took too long to initialise"
org.kde.plasma.libdiscover: Discarding invalid backend "plasmoids.knsrc"
invalid kns backend! "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/colorschemes.knsrc" because: "Backend Colour Schemes took too long to initialise"
org.kde.plasma.libdiscover: Discarding invalid backend "colorschemes.knsrc"
invalid kns backend! "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/ksplash.knsrc" because: "Backend Splash Screens took too long to initialise"
org.kde.plasma.libdiscover: Discarding invalid backend "ksplash.knsrc"
```

So, does anyone know what's the problem? I tried to search for kns, but I didn't find any packages other than `knot-dnsutils`. As its description doesn't fit the errors, I'm assuming the missing KNSBackend is part of another package.

While updating worked, I am not happy with how long it took and I'm wondering how to fix it. I'd be happy to provide additional details if that helps. My Kubuntu 19.10 was originally installed as 18.04 or 18.10 and dist-upgrade'd, and I'm using the amd64 cpu architecture. The only unusual thing in my setup that Ubuntu devs probably don't test often is that I've purged `snapd` and removed `plasma-discover-snap-backend`.

Additional requested information:

```bsh
user@laptop:~$ plasma-discover --version
discover 5.16.5
```

Comment: If you can, please [edit] your question to include the output of `plasma-discover --version`.

Comment: I see a lot of output similar to yours with the latest `plasma-discover` in Kubuntu 20.04 (with Plasma 5.18.4) (as well in another KDE Plasma distro, openSUSE Tumbleweed). I don't use `plasma-discover`. I prefer `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt full-upgrade` in Kubuntu.

Comment: Please take a look at [this very nice explanation](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/76649-5-18-4-Plasma-Discover-took-really-long-to-fetch-KNSBackend?p=435577&viewfull=1#post435577) about the "took really long to fetch" aspect of your output. • Also, instead of re-installing just plasma-discover, trying re-installing `kubuntu-desktop`. That *may* help.

Comment: To know more, look at the files in `/usr/share/knsrcfiles/`. For example, `lookandfeel.knsrc` has this: 
`ProvidersUrl=https://autoconfig.kde.org/ocs/providers.xml`.